# R case insensitive capturing group

Tags: r, regex

This regex :

```
str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , "[a-z]+")
```

returns :

```
[1] "his" "is"  "a"   "est"
```

How to modify so this is case insensitive ?

```
`[1] "This" "is"  "a"   "Test"`
```

should instead be returned

Should `/i` remove case sensitive ?

Trying `str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , "[a-z]+/i")`

returns

```
[[1]]
character(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special notation for [*stringr* functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf):

> `regex(pattern, ignore_case = FALSE, multiline = FALSE, comments = FALSE,
>   dotall = FALSE, ...)`

You may use

```
> str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , regex("[a-z]+", ignore_case=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "This" "is"   "a"    "Test"
```

Alternatively, use an inline `i` modifier `(?i)`:

```
str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , "(?i)[a-z]+")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try including the capital letters in the set you're searching for.

```
str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , "[A-Za-z]+")
```

If you only want the first letter to be capitalized you could try the code below. It lets the first letter be case insensitive and then have only lowercase afterward.

```
str_extract_all("This is a Test , ' ' " , "[A-Za-z][a-z]*")
```